# Is there anyway Natural language Processing (NLP) could be turned ON/OFF, if NLP is present in SP Search 2016

Tags: search, enterprise-search, 2016, people-search

We are using SP 2016- On-Premises Search , in our search when we search anything with "who is working with Java" , the results fairly vary to the search "Java" .

So in that case gone through the content processing component and it looks like words breaker is one of the component used in the Content processing that does the job like Natural Language Processing.

Is there any mechanism/scripts to control the Content Processing components in particular?

Intention is to turn of this intelligence so that we can do some external content processing mechanism and bring the relevant results for the users.

Comment: Not sure if you can turn it off, but have you looked at creating Query Rules to convert the query into something "actionable"?

Comment: Again query rules, I might have to write many number of query rules if I want to run multiple scenarios like this.  Looking for any better alternative.